# On symmetric distributions

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent and identically-distributed random variables with density function $f(\dot\;)$ that is symmetrical about $0$. Show that $$P[\;|X+Y|\leq2|X|\;]>1/2$$
So here is what I have:

I restricted myself into looking only at positive values of $X$, and simply multiply the resulting probability by $2$ since the distribution is symmetric. So after working with the inequalities (and WLOG, assuming both $X$ and $Y$ are continuous), I have:
$$
P[\;|X+Y\leq2|X|\;]=2\int_0^{\infty}\int_{-3x}^xf_Y(y)f_X(x)dydx=2\int_0^{\infty}f_X(x)[F_Y(x)-F_Y(-3x)]dx
$$
$$=2\int_0^{\infty}f_X(x)[F_X(x)-F_X(-3x)]dx\geq2\int_0^{\infty}f_X(x)[F_X(x)-1/2]dx $$
$$
(\text{since}\; F_X(-3x)\leq1/2)\;=2\left[\frac{F_X^2(x)}{2}-\frac{F_X(x)}{2}\right]_0^{\infty}=\frac{1}{4}
$$

That is what I get, instead of $1/2$. Is there anything wrong? And if so, may I ask for help how to go about this? Thanks.

Comment: There is still some unmatched $||$ in the question ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have $F_X(-3x)\leq 1-F_X(x)$.  Does that help?

Comment: Oh! Absolutely it helped! I now got it. Thanks a lot. :)